# циклический switch java

Tags: java, консоль, menu

Мне нужно сделать консольное меню, использовал обычный switch, но не знаю как сделать чтобы при выборе кейса, он выполнялся и после этого в консоли снова появлялось то же меню, без потери проделанных операций

Класс Main

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List list = new List();

    int value;
    int color;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Menu");
    System.out.println("1 - Make list" + "\n" + "2 - Show massive" + "\n" + "3 - Show number of elements" + "\n" +
            "4 - Show cards by the value" + "\n" + "5 - Show cards by color" + "\n" + "6 - Remove" + "\n" + "7 - Quit" + "\n");

    byte functuion = scan.nextByte();

    switch (functuion){

        case 1 : list.makeList();

        case 2 : list.showList();

        case 3 :
            System.out.println("Number of elements: ");
            list.showNumberOfElements();

        case 4 :
            System.out.println("Enter value for search: ");
            scan.nextLine();
            value = scan.nextInt();
            list.showByValue(value);

        case 5 :
            System.out.println("Enter color for search: ");
            scan.nextLine();
            color = scan.nextInt();
            list.showByColor(color);

        case 6 :
            System.out.println("Enter value of card that you want to remove: ");
            value = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter color of card that you want to remove: ");
            color = scan.nextInt();
            list.remove(value, color);

        case 7 : break;

    }

}




}
```

Comment: вы либо потеряли все break либо так задумали, но тогда зачем он в case 7, если он все равно последний?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean cheaker = true;
while(cheaker){
    switch(...){
        ...
        case(...):
            cheaker = false; // выход из меню
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `case(4):` - брррр

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List list = new ArrayList();

        int value;
        int color;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String menu = "Menu\n" + "1 - Make list\n" + "2 - Show massive\n" + "3 - Show number of elements\n"
            + "4 - Show cards by the value\n" + "5 - Show cards by color\n" + "6 - Remove\n" + "7 - Quit\n";

        System.out.println(menu);

        boolean isQuit = false;
        while (!isQuit) {
            byte functuion = scan.nextByte();

            switch (functuion) {

                case 1:
                    // list.makeList();
                    System.out.println("list.makeList();");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    // list.showList();
                    System.out.println("list.showList();");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Number of elements: ");
                    // list.showNumberOfElements();
                    break;

                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Enter value for search: ");
                    scan.nextLine();
                    value = scan.nextInt();
                    // list.showByValue(value);
                    break;

                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Enter color for search: ");
                    scan.nextLine();
                    color = scan.nextInt();
                    // list.showByColor(color);
                    break;

                case 6:
                    System.out.println("Enter value of card that you want to remove: ");
                    value = scan.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter color of card that you want to remove: ");
                    color = scan.nextInt();
                    // list.remove(value, color);
                    break;

                case 7:
                    isQuit = true;
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("No such menu");
                    break;
            }

            System.out.println(menu);
        }

    }

}
```